# Wordpress: Changed HTTP to HTTPS, now security certificate error

Tags: wordpress, security, https

I was trying to secure my website and found a blog on wordpress which shows how to change HTTP to HTTPS from the wordpress settings. I did what it said and now my website won't let me navigate further than the home page. I tried logging into the admin page, but the login screen won't even load and gives a 404 error. I really need to fix this so I can use my site. I tried changing addresses to HTTP instead of HTTPS but it still won't navigate. I've looked through a few php files in my control panel in an attempt to change the URL, but I can't find the right spot.

The security error said that some site anchoragebay was attempting to certify my site which I don't recognize.

Sidenote: I installed the plugin askimet today to my website. Not sure if this also contributed to the problem.

Comment: Please do not use links to illustrate your issue. Copy and paste text, or, if needed, upload and add an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trying to fix this problem, I found a great youtube video. "Fix WordPress Site URL: General Settings Change, Cant Login" I will say how to fix this though in case anyone ever does what I did.

You login to you CPanel>Databases>phpMyAdmin. Go to the database for your site. There should be a file in there with the word "options" in it. Open that file. In there you can change the siteurl and home page url. By changing them back from https to http, the site should go back to working normal!

Answer (score 0):

you can try [find and replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin to replace all http url on https.

> Note: take database [backup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dbmanager/) before doing this for safety.